# Searchable interface - Application force closes

Tags: android

So im making an android app and once trying to go to my last activity my app crashes. Please check to see if there's something im missing.

#### Search1.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Search1 extends Activity {

    String searchtype="null";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);


        Button ISBN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ISBN);  

        ISBN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(View view) {      
                    onSearchRequested();
                    searchtype="ISBN";
             }

        });


        Button Title = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Title);  
    Title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(View view) {      
                    onSearchRequested();
                    searchtype="Title";
             }
    //various listeners follow
        });...
```

#### Searchresults.java

```
public class SearchResults extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.search);

// Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
}
}
```

and finally the manifest for both files

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResults" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

and

```
<activity    android:name=".Search1"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
             <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                        android:value=".SearchResults" /> 
</activity>
```

The Searchresults activity is still incomplete(The xml file only contains a textview) but i still dont think the app should force close when i try to enter the activity. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I usually forget to put in my activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, have you checked if that's the problem? =)

Comment: The manifest for both activities is down there, bottom of my post so it shouldnt be that.